# Append text into div element when click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the below code I append some `input` elements into the `#cls` div. But when I try to type inside the input also new input add. I only need new input when I click "click" text. Can anyone help me. Thank you

```
$('#cls').click(function() {
    var add="<input type="text">"
    $(#cls).append(add);
});
```

```html
<div id="cls">click</div>
```

Comment: Given the syntax errors in your code, I don't understand how it works currently at all.

Comment: do you want new `input`  to append every time you click `cls`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to see whether the click actually happened in the `div`

```js
$('#cls').click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is(this)) { //or !$(e.target).is('input')
    var add = '<input type="text">';
    $(this).append(add);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cls">click</div>
```

Comment: I don't know what OP is trying to achieve, but if you keep on clickinng `click` it appends new input.

Comment: @Arun `if($(e.target).is($(this))){` would also work. can you explain why chose `this` instead of `$(this)`. I guess because if wrap in a jquery object it is more "expensive"?

Answer (score 0):

Append your input to parent element:

```js
var clicked= false;
$('#cls').click(function() {
  if(!clicked){
    var add="<input type='text'>";
    $(this).parent().append(add);
    clicked = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cls'>click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you user .after() method instead of .append() the textbox would appear outside the #cls div and hence clicking the textbox wouldn't cause adding a new one.

Some code

```
$('#cls').click(function() {
  var add="<input type='text'>";
  $('#cls').after(add);
});
```

[Try it out](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxPVqe)

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery's one method. it will register click handler only once.

```
$('#cls').one("click", function(e) {
    var add = '<input type="text">';
    $(this).append(add);
});
```